# How was Sasuke able to summon 2 different types of creatures?

Tags: naruto

Summoning is a technique which is used to summon creatures. Most of the time, many of them were able to summon only 1 type of creature only (like, for Naruto, it's frogs).

But Sasuke is able to summon snakes and hawks. So my question is, how he is able to summon 2 different types of creatures?

Comment: didn't you know Kishimoto is Uchiha fanboy?

Comment: could be that hawks would be natural to Sasuke and the snakes come from the curse mark or something Orichimaru "added" in preparation to make Sasuke his new body

Comment: I think you can have any amount of summons as long as you have blood contracts with them

Comment: Even Konohamaru can summon both Toads and Monkey.

Answer (score 6):

Well officially, only Pain and Sasuke are able to summon more than one creature. Pain's ability seems more realistic since each summoned animal had the black rods (he may have gotten control of their dead bodies and utilized them during battles with his vast chakra).

Sasuke is a different issue. There's no evidence that he ever signed off a contract with the hawks. Seems like Kishimoto pulled it off just to blend with the 'Taka' group name.

Comment: I don't think it's said anywhere Pain can only summon those animals because of the rods. I believe those rods are simply there to reflect Nagato's Rinnegan on all the pierced people. Most likely can summon multiple species due to the Animal Path.

Answer (score 6):

Although it's never mentioned the possibility of having two contracts, it's also never mentioned that it is impossible to do so. I wouldn't call it a plot hole, because it wasn't contradictory with pre-established rules.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Sasuke's contract with the Snakes ended after his fight with Deidra and he signed with the Hawks.

I don't know how he get the scroll but that's what it looks like.

In *Boruto Series*, we might get to see his summoning jutsu again because currently he is Boruto's teacher now.

We will get to watch him teach Boruto how to do the summoning jutsu and other more things. So all we can do is wait.

Comment: Can you add some sources or additional details?

Comment: It did not end, in the war you summoned a snake

Answer (score 0):

Snakes could be the summoning that Orochimaru taught him but hawks could be his own summoning. His snake summons also didn't die after his fight with Deidara because he was shown using Aoda during the Fourth Shinobi War.

Answer (score -3):

It is possible that his snake summons died after his fight with Deidara making it possible for him to make another contract.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33972)

Comment: How does this not answer the question? saying that his snake summons died making it possible for him to make a second contract seems to decidedly answer the question.

Comment: Do you have any sources to suggest that he made a second pact with the hawks at all?